# Rails 4.2 InvalidAuthenticityToken error, but only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm making this little app that uses (more or less) the sessions management code from https://www.railstutorial.org/book.

It works fine in development mode, and if running in production mode on my development machine. When I deploy to a machine running nginx and Phusion Passenger, I start getting InvalidAuthenticityToken on every request, where a token is used (forms and links with `method: delete` for example).

I have verified that the token is generated and is sent along with the request.

I have noticed one thing. The main area of the app at `/` is open to all and does not require any kind of login. The area needing login is at `/admin`. When running in development, one session cookie is generated with a path of `/`. When deployed, there are two session cookies, one for `/` and one for `/admin`. I suspect that the CSRF token is generated using one session and then validated using the other session.

Does this sound plausible? How would I go about investigating this further and fixing it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regenerate a new token using this command - rake secret

Comment: @CaffeineCoder what would that help? That just prints out a randomly generated token.

Comment: You need to paste it in secret_token.rb

Comment: @CaffeineCoder that file is not used after Rails 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is linked to bugs regarding cookies in Phusion Passenger 5 beta:

[Session being emptied on POST requests in 5.0.0-beta2](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1349)

Downgrading to 4.0.57 fixed the problems.